# JSF inputfile : array of files to upload (syntax)

Tags: java, jsf

Does my syntax is wrong to manage an array of files to upload?

In my java bean:

```
private List<Part> files = new ArrayList<Part>();

public void setFiles(List<Part> files) {
    this.files = files;
}
public List<Part> getFiles() {
    return files;
}
```

In my xhtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h:inputFile id="file1" value="#{theBean.files[0]}">
    </h:inputFile>
    <p:message for="file1"/>
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{fn:length(theBean.files) > 1}">
        <h:inputFile id="file2" value="#{theBean.files[1]}">
        </h:inputFile>
    </ui:fragment>
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{fn:length(theBean.files) > 2}">
        <h:inputFile id="file3" value="#{theBean.files[2]}">
        </h:inputFile>
    </ui:fragment>
</div>
```

I have an array of files to upload defined in my java code and I want to use the index of the array in the xhtml.  The java code is not called.   What is the better solution and keeping the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your list is empty.

```
System.out.println(files.size()); // 0
```

As `Part` is immutable, you'd better use a list of mutable beans instead.

```
public class UploadedFile {
    private Part value;
    // Getter+setter.
}
```

```
private List<UploadedFile> files = new ArrayList<>();

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    files.add(new UploadedFile());
    files.add(new UploadedFile());
    System.out.println(files.size()); // 2
}
```

```html
<h:inputFile value="#{bean.files[0].value}" />
```

Or alternatively use a plain vanilla array instead which you can preinitialize with a fixed size.

```
private Part[] files = new Part[2]; // 2 items.
```

Comment: with List<Part> or Part[], the setter in the bean is not called.  what would be the syntax to call ajax within inputfile with the List<Part> or Part[]?

Comment: When the page is submitted and an error is thrown, the page is refreshed and the inputFile are lost (null).  I need to keep the files.

Comment: The setter of the colleciton in the bean is indeed never called. You can safely remove it. Instead the item is set on the specified index. It's under the covers basically `bean.getUploadedFiles().get(0).setValue(part)`. The syntax is already given in the answer. As to the files being lost, just use Ajax instead to update only the error messages instead of the whole page.

Comment: What I meant is after the user enters the file to upload and submit the page, the user can receive an error because one mandatory field on the page is empty and the uploaded file has disappear.  How can I keep the files in the page?

Comment: Use Ajax to submit the form and update only the error messages instead of the whole page.